# AdMob Native Video Ads for ViewPager2?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, admob, native-ads

I am using viewpager2 with RecyclerViewAdapter for displaying list of videos and to monetize my app i wanted to place ads after every 5th element, my question is-

Does Admob provides Native Video Ads for this? if yes how we can use/implement it?

If any other suggestion which ads to use for this situations??

Comment: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-native-advanced-feed-android/#0

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course Admob provides native ads.
Populate your list with native ads whereever you want and you can easily display in viewpager2 adapter accordingly with the help of viewtype.

Google Admob example - https://github.com/googlecodelabs/admob-native-advanced-feed/archive/master.zip